# Android Update/Refresh TextView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm fighting with problem. I want my Textviews to display Integer values and be refreshed every second.

My Integer Objects

```
  public Integer Money[] = new Integer[1];

 public void MoneyMaker(int count,int c){
        Money[c] = count;
    }

 public void MakeMoney(){
        int count = 0;
        MoneyMaker(0, count);
    }
```

In MainActivity I reach them as

```
MainHolder Main = new MainHolder();
```

I got textview like these:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="Money: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MoneyText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_Money"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Money"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_Money"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

  <TextView
        android:text="Box: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BoxesText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_Boxes"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Boxes"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_Boxes"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
```

Got "ĢameLoop" in mainActivity onCreate method

```
   Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Refresh();
                            SaveFile();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

And got Refresh method

```
 public void Refresh(){
    TextView MoneyTXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MoneyText);
    MoneyTXT.setText("Money: " +Main.Money[0]);
    TextView BoxesTXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BoxesText);
    BoxesTXT.setText("Boxes: " +Main.Boxes[0]);
}
```

OnCreate Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    LoadFile();

    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Refresh();
                            SaveFile();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

I don't show any error in code, but when launching app, it automatically shuts of.
In logcat, got error:

```
11-07 19:10:10.007 29809-29809/com.crelix.crelix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.crelix.crelix, PID: 29809
                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.crelix.crelix.NavigationActivity.Refresh(NavigationActivity.java:147)
                                                                   at com.crelix.crelix.NavigationActivity$1$1.run(NavigationActivity.java:66)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where are initialize Main.Money[0] and Main.Boxes[0] ?

Comment: Please post whole class.

Comment: @ShoebSiddique Whole Class are to big, 20k lines, but will post any necessary things

Comment: The TextView is null. Post the code that runs `setContentView`, and make sure that is before you ever run `Refresh()`

Comment: @cricket_007 Added code, if you mean "onCreate" class

Comment: I don't think your TextViews are in the same layout file as your `drawer_layout` and `nav_view` elements. Is that correct?

Comment: That is a method, not a class. `NavigationActivity` is the class

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I got many Fragments. And Textviews are in one of them.

Comment: You can't find a Fragment's TextViews from an Activity. You have to update them from the Fragment itself. If you provided a [mcve], maybe we could help you more, but there is not enough detail here

Comment: @cricket_007 Okey, thanks. I will try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

as error shows, the textview remain null even after initialisation,
it means.

the issue with inflating the layout.

1. maybe forgot or inflate after your method called Refresh().
2. inflated layout don't contain that textview.(due to another version of the same layout like landscape and portrait or multiple size layout)

check once and let me know if the issue is still there.

Happy Coding

Comment: I added my Refresh method lines into my Fragment "onCreateView" method. Now it shows, but my problem now is refreshing fragment. becouse my refresh method dosn't work in fragment.